# jqgrid alignment of body and header in FF, IE

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqgrid working perfectly in chrome.  However in IE and FF I see this:
[image]

The column headers cells are not lining up with the body of the table cells.

Here is the relevant code:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.defaults, {

    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'GET',
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: false,
        id: "Id"
    },
    pager: '#pager',
    rowNum: 10,
    page: '1',
    sortname: 'Name',
    sortorder: 'asc',
    viewrecords: true,
    caption: null,
    height: 'auto',
    scroll: false,
    altRows: true,
    altclass: 'altrow',
    autowidth: true,
    forceFit: true,
    rowTotal: 0,
    loadonce: true,
    shrinkToFit: true,
    pginput: false,
    autoencode: true,
    multiselect: false,
    width: '100%'
});
```

and the specific table:

```
$("#ctable").jqGrid({
                    data: mydata,
                    datatype: "local",
                    colNames: ['Date', 'Urls', 'Errors', 'Warnings', 'Infos', 'Time', 'Size', 'Delete', 'Id Hidden'],
                    colModel: [
                            { name: 'Date', sorttype: "date", width: 2, datefmt: "m/d/Y H:i:s",editrules:{date:true} },
                            { name: 'UrlCount', sorttype: "int", width: 1 },
                            { name: 'ViolationsError', sorttype: "string", width: 1, formatter:violationserrorformatter },
                            { name: 'ViolationsWarning', sorttype: "string", width: 1, formatter:violationswarningformatter },
                            { name: 'ViolationsInfo', sorttype: "string", width: 1, formatter:violationsinfoformatter },
                            { name: 'TimeElapsed', sorttype: "date", width: 1, datefmt: "H:i:s",editrules:{date:true}  },
                            { name: 'Size', sorttype: "number", width: 1 },
                            { name: 'Delete', sorttype: "", width: 1, align:"center" },
                            { name: 'Id', sorttype: "int", width: 1, hidden:true }
                        ],
                    sortname: 'Date',
                    sortorder: 'desc',
                    rowNum:20
                });
```

I have tried taking out stylesheets, js, the surrounding template html and even taking out a few of the columns and it seems this error is still present in the alignment.  Im stuck, any ideas?

Comment: You should include full code of the demo. Having of the picture only is not enough for debugging. :-)

Comment: revised to include code, sorry about that!

Comment: Sorry, but the information which you post is not enough to reproduce the problem. For example you use tree custom formatters: `violationserrorformatter`, `violationswarningformatter`, `violationsinfoformatter`, The `'Delete'` column seams be also not empty on your picture. The test data for `mydata` would be additional needed. So if you have suspect that you found a bug you need really full code (sometime HTML code also) which can be used to reproduce the problem. Which versions of jQuery, jqGrid, jQuery UI (and which theme) you use? In which versions of IE and FF you tested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I examined you demo which you post me per email and find out that you made modifications of the original `ui.jqgrid.css` of jqGrid. Together with other changes you increased the `padding` of `th` elements to `7px`:

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th.ui-th-column
{
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    background-color:#EEE;
    padding:7px;
}
```

You should use default `padding-right: 2px` and `padding-left: 2px` to have correct calculated column widths.

I don't recommend you to change `border-width`, `padding-right`, `padding-left`, `margin-left` and `margin-right` of and `th` or `td` elements of the grid.

Comment: this is spot on correct.  I should have figured the styling was taken into account for the calculations, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Insert this block of code into the `gridComplete` event of your grid. Replace `gridName` with your grid `id` and that's it! :)

```
var objHeader = $("table[aria-labelledby=gbox_" + gridName+ "] tr[role=rowheader] th");

for (var i = 0; i < objHeader.length; i++) {
   var col = $("table[id=" + gridName+ "] td[aria-describedby=" + objHeader[i].id + "]");
   var width= col.outerWidth();
   $(objHeader[i]).css("width", width);
}
```

Works with v.4.6.0.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me..

$($('.ui-jqgrid-bdiv').find('table')[0]).css('max-width', 'none')